# Change Url Path from /auth/ CodeIgniter and Ionauth

Tags: php, codeigniter, ion-auth

This is probably a really simple question but I am entirely new to codeigniter. I am using ionauth for a secure account system but I would like to change the url path, simply changing the class name is not working, it simply gives me a 404 whenever I try access it. I am trying to change the `/auth/` location to `/account/` but when I try it by just renaming `class Auth extends CI_Controller {` to `class Account extends CI_Controller {` it does not work as expected.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated,
Again I am new to this so please go easy it's probably a simple fix and me not know code igniter very well.

Thanks,
Simon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `application/config/config.php` file ,you can set your base URL.Base URL should be absolute, including the protocol:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://somesite.com/somedir/";
```

If using the URL helper, then `base_url()` will output the above string.

For url routing you can use like this `$route['account/login'] = "auth/login"`

Comment: Sorry I was probably not to clear with my subject so changed it, I believe changing the base_url will change the entire website. I just want to change the ion_auth path if you look at userfarmer.com you will see what I mean, it takes you to /auth/login I want it to be /account/login/

Comment: you can use CI routing.Have a look here http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Comment: look something like this
$route['account/login'] = "auth/login";